# logging events with an inline onevent listener

Tags: javascript, html

I want to do an inline catch of an event and console.log data from the event like this `<select onchange="(e)=>{console.log(e.target.value)}">` but I can't get it to work. I'm guessing it's not allowed to define a method like this.

It works with no variables and plain method call like this `<select onchange="console.log('foo')">` and of course if I define a method somewhere else I can call that and get the event, but is there no way to get the event variable and log it directly?

Comment: Your listener works as it is, but it doesn't do what you think it does. You're just defining an anonymous function, you never call that function. It's a bit like you'd make hard work on a code for a long day, and at the end of the day you'd just shut down the machine, and never saved your work.

Comment: what happens if you change `onchange="(e)=>{console.log(e.target.value)}"` to `onchange="(e)=>{console.log(e)}"`?  then look at the debugger... You see option selected in there??

Comment: Yes of course - I'm not calling it. Modified it to this and it works `onchange="((e)=>{console.log(arguments[0].target.value)})()"`

Answer (score 0):

For reference if someone finds this question.

As Teemu said, in my question I'm just defining an anonymous function. I got it to work by using IIFE and arguments like this `onchange="((e)=>{console.log(arguments[0].target.value)})()"`